# How to preserve user login session time until he not log out in asp.net using vb.net?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
        date_time = Now.ToString("hh:mm, MMM-dd-yy")
        Dim constrng As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("cs").ConnectionString
        If Session("user_id") Is Nothing Then
            Response.Redirect("Login.aspx")
        Else
            Welcome_id.Text = "Welcome " + Session("user_id").ToString
            fill_zone()
            grid_view_load()
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Want to user login session and connection string as globally

Comment: I've managed to fix your code formatting (hint - use the `{}` button for code samples, and use the preview window to check what your question looks like), but I'm not actually sure what your question is. Could you try explaining more, or differently?

Comment: You already know about Session variables. Why is that not a solution? Please add that to your question.

Comment: after login user session start and its login time must be saved in the varibale  and user may be visit to many pages and after that if user click on logout button then its current time must be saved in the database.... thats my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code example sets the timeout session attribute to 30 minutes in the Web.config file.

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <sessionState 
      mode="InProc"
      cookieless="true"
      timeout="30" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

also check in iis what the sessiontimeout is set to.

Comment: I just want to store the user login time in date_time variable but want to use this variable as globally... how to do this

Comment: My question is that can we retrive date and time from session if yes then how......????

Comment: Response.write(Session("user_id")) will show you the value on any page of your website. so yes you can use Session("user_id") anywhere to get its assigned value.

Comment: Session("user_id") = date_time , then on any page use Session("user_id") to get its value.